# How to get the string to Json format

Tags: php, json, curl

How to convert a JSON string into an array for [this query](http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/)?

Request code:

```
$cookies=tmpfile();
$ch = curl_init("https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&callback=&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1jNPyLFXXXXXxXFXXXXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);//используем куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
substr($page, 0, -1);
$json = json_decode($page,true);
print_r($page);
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: why you are printing $page.

Comment: @Anant do not get to json format in php error check here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @mega94 can you please update the question , what the actual problem is??

Comment: @Riyaz convert a string in json format, and display the desired array, but for some reason it is impossible to convert.

Comment: @mega94 you have to put your solution as an answer and marked it as an answer for others help. but also add description how you resolve your error. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you should try this it will work

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data=file_get_contents("http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data. A numeric 1 is present at the end of the file. Please remove it.

Comment: The problem is solved: `$cookies=tmpfile();
$ch = curl_init("https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&callback=json&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1jNPyLFXXXXXxXFXXXXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);//используем куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = substr($page, 7, -2);
$json = json_decode($json);
print_r($json);`